# Mapping class group interpretation of braid closure

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, braid-groups

Given a braid (diagram) $\beta\in B_n$, the associated closed braid is the knot/link formed by attaching the ends on which the strings lie. We can also, however, think of $\beta$ as being an element of the mapping class group of the $n$-punctured disc $\text{Mod}(D_n)$. Is there a geometric interpretation of closed braids that comes from the mapping class group viewpoint?

Comment: 1) You can describe the exterior of the closed braid using the element of your mapping class group. 2) More generally, if you build a surface bundle over $S^1$ using an element of the mapping class group, the geometry of the 3-manifold is related to the Thurston decomposition of the mapping class.

Comment: This question seems vague to me.  What do you mean by “geometric interpretation”? Also, the usual notion of braid closure gives a knot or link in the three-sphere.  This (usual notion) is very subtle, and is only loosely related to the dynamics/geometry of mapping classes.

Comment: (In fact, one of the reasons that the Jones polynomial is amazing is that it manages to eat braids but still spit out a link invariant, via the closure operation.)